# Does DLNA software exist for the full display?

Tags: wireless-networking, hdmi, dlna

I'm new to DLNA.  I know that I can use the "Play To" feature to send movies over DLNA to my SmartTV.  Does software exist to send the whole display over DLNA for screen mirroring?

Answer (score 2):

DLNA is for streaming stored files. It can be buffered, which means it has higher latency than you want for screen mirroring. Screen mirroring needs to be unbuffered, low-latency so you can use it interactively without frustrating lag.

For interactive screen mirroring, there's a lot of noise, but there are basically only two solutions:

- Apple's AirPlay Screen Mirroring (as opposed to "AirTunes/AirPlay Audio", "AirPlay Video", and "iTunes Home Sharing", which are more like Apple's DLNA equivalents).
- Miracast, an industry consortium response to AirPlay Mirroring. Miracast hasn't worked out very well, partly because every company has put their own brand name on their Miracast support (for example, Intel's Wireless Display or "WiDi" technology was a proprietary thing for a while, but is now basically just their name for their Miracast support), and partly because apparently the companies involved in Miracast don't do enough interoperability testing:
  [image: interoperability testing]

See also: [How-To Geek: Wireless Display Standards Explained: AirPlay, Miracast, WiDi, Chromecast, and DLNA](http://www.howtogeek.com/177145/wireless-display-standards-explained-airplay-miracast-widi-chromecast-and-dlna/)